# Como saber si una fecha tiene más de 2 semanas SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-management, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

bueno me gustaria hacer una consulta la cual me traiga algunos datos de mi tabla  y ademas tenga como filtro que solamente me traiga los registros que tengan más de dos semanas a dia de hoy pero no se como realizar esto, alguien me podria ayudar con esto?... bueno esta es mi tabla:

```
ID     Docente                        Años      JefeID   FechaIngreso
1      Jose Maria Jimenez               34          5      2021-10-22
2      Erika Gonzales Muñoz             32          5      1997-02-15
3      Juan Carlos Herrera              28       Null      2022-12-19
4      Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez         43          8      2023-03-07
5      Ricardo Zamarripa Delgado        25          3      2007-11-02    
6      Alejandro Hernandez Castillo     34          8      2023-03-07
7      Paola Contreras Fernandez        41       Null      2023-02-22
8      Luis Alberto Gutierrez Macias    40          7      2021-10-08
```

Tengo esta consulta, pero no se como agregarla en where:

```
select ID, Docente, DATEDIFF(week,FechaIngreso,GETDATE())
from Docentes
order by FechaIngreso desc
```

Comment: Pero intentaste algo??? es un simple where con un date_diff

Comment: Deje la consulta que hice, pero no se como hacer el where ya que ya saque las semanas que tienen segun su fecha

Comment: buenisimo!! eso mismo en el where mayor a 2 semanas.. no?

Comment: no, no serviría si usa `WEEK`, dependiendo de qué tan exacto se necesita, podrías usar `DAY` mayor a 14

Comment: @gbianchi- Ciertisimo, no se porque antes me estaba marcando error en toda la expresion pero si con eso ya esta, te lo agradezco :)

Comment: Leinad, ojo, mira el comentario acertadisimo de @Lamak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres las filas que tengan más de 2 semanas de antigüedad, tienes 2 opciones. Verificar que la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la fecha a comparar sea mayor a 2 semanas (o 14 días como mencionaron en los comentarios), u comparar directamente la fecha contra la fecha de hace 2 semanas.

La función DATEDIFF() no funciona como diferencia exacta sino que funciona contando los saltos entre periodos. Por ejemplo, tanto `DATEDIFF(YYYY, '20210101', '20221231')` como `DATEDIFF(YYYY, '20211231', '20220101')` regresarán 1 como resultado aunque en una la diferencia sea un día y en la otra más de 700 días. Por ello es que te recomiendan usar días en vez de semanas para obtener la diferencia.

Sin embargo, otro consejo más importante es el de no usar funciones en las columnas que utilizas en los filtros. Esto es porque evitas que se puedan utilizar índices para buscar las filas y se tenga que leer toda la tabla (aunque en esta consulta es probable que haga eso por la distribución de información). Entonces, la mejor opción es ver cuales tienen una fecha más antigua comparando con la fecha de hace 2 semanas.

```
SELECT ID, 
        Docente, 
        DATEDIFF( DAY, FechaIngreso, GETDATE()) / 14 AS SemanasAntiguedad
FROM Docentes
WHERE FechaIngreso < CAST( DATEADD( WEEK, -2, GETDATE()) AS date) --Convertimos a date para eliminar la hora
```